# When is forward declaration not enough?

Tags: c++, class, overloading, definition, incomplete-type

The #include problem

```
class widget { };

class fubar : public widget { // 1

    void value_parameter(widget); // 2    
    void ref_parameter(widget &); // 3
    void ptr_parameter(widget *); // 4

    virtual void value_parameter(widget); // 5
    virtual void ref_parameter(widget &); // 6
    virtual void ptr_parameter(widget *); // 7

    widget value_return(); // 8
    widget & ref_return(); // 9
    widget * ptr_return(); // 10

    widget instance_value_member; // 11
    widget & instance_ref_member; // 12
    widget * instance_ptr_member; // 13

    static widget static_value_member; // 14
    static widget & static_ref_member; // 15
    static widget * static_ptr_member; // 16
};
```

Which of those lines require a has include?  (`#include "widget.hpp"`)

Comment: Which lines do you think it is, and why?

Comment: The code implies `widget` is provided just before `fubar`, but the rest of the question's text implies the opposite. If its the first case, you don't need the `#include` at all for any of the members (`widget` is already provided). If it's the second, just the fact that you inherit from `widget` means you need the `#include` regardless of the rest of `fubar`'s definition.

Comment: @Sergio Legaz Ruiz You forgot to mark this line  class fubar : public widget {..:)

Comment: Welcome to StackOverflow! Please choose a more descriptive title; the title as-is is unlikely to help a future visitor.

Comment: .... to put it kindly

Answer (score 5):

Full definition of `Widget` is required for:

- `#1` (`class fubar : public widget`), we need base class definition.
- `#11` (`widget instance_value_member;`), we need member definition.

Forward declarations is enough for the others.

Comment: What about #8? #14?

Comment: @LightnessRacesinOrbit It is a declaration not a definition.:) It may have an incomplete type.

Comment: [Holy sh!t TIL](http://coliru.stacked-crooked.com/a/6cd948992e7f8435)

Comment: @LightnessRacesinOrbit Yup, this surprised me too recently. It seems that a full definition is only needed where it affects the size of an instance of the class. I imagine everything else is left to the linker.

Answer (score 3):

None.

`class widget { };` defines a *complete type*.

It would have been a different matter had you written `class widget;` i.e. a *forward class declaration*. Then given that you'd need a *complete type* due to the inheritance, there would be no further `#include` necessary for the functions.

Comment: I suspect that was purely for exposition, though I concede the question was not well-framed.

Comment: @LightnessRacesinOrbit: You gotta answer what's asked. Methinks "It would have been a different matter" shows enough initiative on my part ;-)

Answer (score 1):

I think you mean a forward declaration

```
class widget;
```

instead of the definition

```
class widget { };
```

In this case the first header line of the class declaration

```
class fubar : public widget { // 1
```

requires a complete type definition of widget. Otherwise the size of the class fubar will be unknown.

All other declarations do not require a compete type definition of widget except this line

```
widget instance_value_member; // 11
```

Take into account that static data members may have incomplete types because they are declarations in a class definition (except when they are declared with the specifier constexpr). So this line for example

```
static widget static_value_member; // 14
```

does not require the complete type definition of widget.

Also you may not overload member functions the following way

```
void value_parameter(widget); // 2    
void ref_parameter(widget &); // 3
void ptr_parameter(widget *); // 4

virtual void value_parameter(widget); // 5
virtual void ref_parameter(widget &); // 6
virtual void ptr_parameter(widget *); // 7
```

that is to overload virtual and non-virtual functions with the same names and parameter lists.

Comment: @Jarod42 In general the compiler can not select a function based on whether its parametert is a reference or not.

Comment: @Jarod42 Oh, I did not see that.:)